# How can I animate shrinking of a uiwebview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, core-animation

I'm trying to shrink a webview smoothly when the keyboard appears, but I'm having trouble with the animation. As soon as the animation is created, the webview's content shrinks to its new frame. After the animation delay, the webview itself animates properly to its new size.

The screenshots below show what it looks like. I've set the background of the web view's scroll view to yellow and the background of the view controller view to green.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

How can I have the content animate smoothly with the webView? This is the code I have for the animation.

```
-(void)shrinkWebView {
    __weak CDVPlugin* weakSelf = self;
    CGRect frame = weakSelf.webView.frame;
    frame.size.height -= 400;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:3.0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         weakSelf.webView.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks for the help

Here's the stripped down version of the cordova sample app I'm working with.

```css
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* make transparent link selection, adjust last value opacity 0 to 1.0 */
}

body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
    -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
    background-color:#E4E4E4;
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #A7A7A7),
        color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4)
    );
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:100%;
}

/* Portrait layout (default) */
.app {
    background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center top; /* 170px x 200px */
    position:absolute;             /* position in the center of the screen */
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    height:50px;                   /* text area height */
    width:225px;                   /* text area width */
    text-align:center;
    padding:180px 0px 0px 0px;     /* image height is 200px (bottom 20px are overlapped with text) */
    margin:-115px 0px 0px -112px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height and text area height */
                                   /* offset horizontal: half of text area width */
}

/* Landscape layout (with min-width) */
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (min-width:400px) {
    .app {
        background-position:left center;
        padding:75px 0px 75px 170px;  /* padding-top + padding-bottom + text area = image height */
        margin:-90px 0px 0px -198px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height */
                                      /* offset horizontal: half of image width and text area width */
    }
}

h1 {
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:visible;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

.event {
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0px 30px;
    padding:2px 0px;
}

.event.listening {
    background-color:#333333;
    display:block;
}

.event.received {
    background-color:#4B946A;
    display:none;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1.0; }
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1.0; }
}
 
.blink {
    animation:fade 3000ms infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fade 3000ms infinite;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <button onclick="Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(false)">Shrink</button>
            <input type="text" />
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be much better to animate the `scrollView.contentInset` property only, not the entire frame... I don't see why you need to `delay` (it can be `0.0`), and you can use the keyboard animation's duration for your animation's duration, which is `0.25` currently (but you can read the current value from the notification which posted when the keyboard will appear).

Comment: @holex I'm just using those larger values so the problem is more visible. I just tried using the contentInset property. On 7.1 it has a similar issue. The content immediately shrinks leaving empty black space, then the scrollview's contentInset shrinks with the animation. On 8.1 it doesn't animate at all.

Comment: @connor there are a handful of solutions to this. Are you using Auto Layout? Storyboard or is everything programmatic?

Comment: @Firo I believe it's done programmatically. I'm working within cordova, so I didn't implement the view controller myself.

Answer (score 4):

What about resizing document.body.style.height via javascript?

```
- (void)resizeWebView:(UIWebView *)webView toHeight:(CGFloat)height duration:(CGFloat)duration {
    // We will wrap all webView contents with div and animate it's size
    // so webView content will resize independently of webView's frame.
    NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""
            "function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time) {\n"
            "    var start = new Date().getTime(),\n"
            "        timer = setInterval(function() {\n"
            "            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);\n"
            "            elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;\n"
            "            if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);\n"
            "        }, 25);\n"
            "    elem.style[style] = from+unit;\n"
            "}\n"
            "document.body.style.position = 'relative';\n"
            "animate(document.body, 'height', 'px', document.body.offsetHeight, %f, %f)",
        height, duration*1000];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];

    BOOL isGrowing = height > webView.frame.size.height;

    // If webView is growing, change it's frame imediately, so it's content not clipped during animation
    if (isGrowing) {
        CGRect frame = webView.frame;
        frame.size.height = height;
        webView.frame = frame;
    }

    __weak typeof(webView) weakWebView = webView;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        __strong typeof(weakWebView) webView = weakWebView;
        // If webview was shrinking, change it's frame after animation is complete
        if (!isGrowing) {
            CGRect frame = webView.frame;
            frame.size.height = height;
            webView.frame = frame;
        }
        // Remove remove body position constraints
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""
                "document.body.style.position = document.body.style.height = null;"
        ];
    });
}

- (void)toggleButtonTapped:(id)sender {
     [self resizeWebView:self.webView toHeight:300 duration:0.4];
}
```

[image: Example]

**Edit:** Updated code, now all html is wrapped with `<div style="position:relative;">`, so absolutely positioned elements are animated too.

**Edit 2:** Ok, manipulation DOM structure wasn't good idea – if you were trying to resize webView when user focuses input inside webView and keyboard appears, input was loosing focus and keyboard was immediately hidden. So now I just add `document.body.style.position = 'relative'` to code and resize body.

I also created [category on UIWebView](https://github.com/glyuck/GLKAnimateWebViewFrame), you can install it via cocoapods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you share some more of your code? I'm calling your function from a button press and still seeing the jumping behavior

Comment: @connor added some sample code. If this function doesn't work for you, probably there is some problem with html you trying to resize. Maybe you need to resize another node, not body. Can you paste html+css of your page to somewhere?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking. I wasn't doing anything more in objc than calling your method on a button press.

Comment: I've added some html/css

Comment: Ok, updated code, now it should work with your html. The problem was in `position: absolute;` in your `.app` div. It's position was only recalculated on window size change and was unrelated to body.height (which I was animating). Now I wrap all html with `<div style="position:relative;">` and animate it's height. So all absolutely positioned elements' positions are animated too.

Comment: @connor another update for code. It was not good idea to manipulate page's DOM. Also created pod, hope it will save someone's time. Feel free to add issues and pull requests :-)

Comment: Yeah I noticed the keyboard issue. The update works much better. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *webViewBottomConstraint;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyBoardShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyBoardShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyBoardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Keyboard Notification
-(void)keyBoardShow:(NSNotification*)noti
{

    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[noti.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    NSNumber *duration = [noti.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];

    // Need to translate the bounds to account for rotation.
    keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration.floatValue animations:^{
        [self.webViewBottomConstraint setConstant:keyboardBounds.size.height];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

}

-(void)keyBoardHide:(NSNotification*)noti
{

    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[noti.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    NSNumber *duration = [noti.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration.floatValue animations:^{
        [self.webViewBottomConstraint setConstant:0];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

}

@end
```

Hopes it could help you.

Comment: Hi Steve. What is `webViewBottomConstraint`? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer can be in the Apple documentation:

Listing 5-1  Handling the keyboard notifications

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1

Basically subscribe to the keyboard appearance to do the animation yourself.

Comment: The issue is with the animation. The webview's size animates properly with the keyboard, but its content jumps immediately to the new size. I can reproduce with or without the keyboard notifications.

Comment: HO I get it!Then I believe you're not going to like the answer... for my experience with webviews you can't have all that much control from the iOS site. The html reacts to the keyboard, if you want to fix that, you'll have to use js (I see you're probably using a js library to display stuff) to change the positions of the elements. I did that myself but I don't have access to the code :(. The fix is through the js bridge.

Comment: It's not the keyboard in my case. I made a basic test case (show in the screen shots) that triggers the animation on a button click.